# Why is my function running into infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have recently began learning Python, appreciate your response on this.

I have written the definition of **get_int()** and **get_float()** differently on purpose because I wanted to understand what happens if I accept the input in **main()** and pass that value during function call. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def get_int(prompt, low, high):
    while True:
        #number = float(input(prompt))
        if prompt <= low or prompt > high:
            print("Entry should be greater than ", low, "and less than or equal to ", high)
        else:
            return prompt

def get_float(prompt, low, high):
    while True:
        number = float(input(prompt))
        if number <= low or number > high:
            print("Entry should be greater than ", low, "and less than or equal to ", high)
        else:
            return number    
        
def calculate_future_value(monthly_investment, yearly_interest, years):
    # convert yearly values to monthly values
    monthly_interest_rate = yearly_interest / 12 / 100
    months = years * 12

    # calculate future value
    future_value = 0.0
    for i in range(months):
        future_value += monthly_investment
        monthly_interest = future_value * monthly_interest_rate
        future_value += monthly_interest

    return future_value

def main():
    years = 0
    monthly_investment = 0.0
    yearly_interest_rate = 0.0
    choice = "y"
    while choice.lower() == "y":
        # get input from the user
        monthly_investment = get_float("Enter monthly investment: ", 0, 1000)
        yearly_interest_rate = get_float("Enter yearly interest rate: ", 0, 15)
        years = int(input("Enter number of years: "))
        years = get_int(years, 0, 15)

        # get and display future value
        future_value = calculate_future_value(
            monthly_investment, yearly_interest_rate, years)

        print(f"Future value:\t\t\t{round(future_value, 2)}")
        print()

        # see if the user wants to continue
        choice = input("Continue? (y/n): ")
        print()

    print("Bye!")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am having problem only with the **get_int()**. As you see, I have passed **low=0** and **high=15**. If I input years as 0 or 16, then it displays infinite print statement specified in the "if" clause but there is no problem when I input value within the range (see screenshot: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1w4-IhBveZQv0pSDygc1HexNFBDUDNE-B).

I'm not entirely sure if I can use the function argument directly in the function definition without assigning to a local variable.

If it is indeed allowed, is there a mistake with my "while" loop inside **get_int()**? or do I include a while loop in the main() itself where I'm accepting the int value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `prompt` is not correct, you don't update its value. If you don't update its value, the condition won't change. If it doesn't change, you will only print the text and never return.

## Refresh `prompt` value if it's wrong

You still need to refresh the value somewhere if the user input is wrong. If you don't want to ask at the beginning of the loop, ask when the prompt is wrong.

```py
def get_int(prompt, low, high):
    while True:
        if prompt <= low or prompt > high:
            print("Entry should be greater than ", low, "and less than or equal to ", high)
            prompt = int(input("Enter a new value"))  # You need to ask a new value
        else:
            return prompt
```

### Alternative:

You can put the if condition directly in the while loop:

```py
def get_int(prompt, low, high):
    while prompt <= low or prompt > high:
        print("Entry should be greater than ", low, "and less than or equal to ", high)
        prompt = int(input("Enter a new value"))
    return prompt
```

Doing so, you quit the loop right away if the prompt is correct. If it is not, you print the message and refresh the value.

Comment: Sure thing but why is it printing it infinite times? Shouldn't it print the message once? Considering my function definition is incorrect, do I mention any escape statement under the "if" clause?

Comment: infinite loop because the value of prompt never change, so the result of the if won't either. That's why I recommended to update the prompt.

Comment: @Learner I updated my question to make this explanation less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

`while True:` within the `get_int` is indeed an infinite loop, that `while` can i.e. be broken by executing a `return` (which you do on the else case) or a `break` statement. Since you don't execute any similar statement in your `if`, the loop continues.

As it seems by your question, you don't want a loop at all, therefore, you could just declare the `get_int` as:

```
def get_int(prompt, low, high):
    #number = float(input(prompt))
    if prompt <= low or prompt > high:
        print("Entry should be greater than ", low, "and less than or equal to ", high)
    else:
        return prompt
```